# Microsoft Word don't load script for text behind

Tags: office-2010, word-2010

I don't know where to ask, but does anyone got this problem in MS word ?

Instead of text that i expecting, i got this ?
[image]
[image]

Really appreciated for any kind help.

Comment: Simply toggle between field codes and values by pressing `ALT+F9`.

Comment: savior :) I don't know those shortcuts :)

Comment: Bonus shortcut: `CTRL+F9` inserts a new (general purpose) field you can right-click and configure to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Is this when printing?

In file/Options/Advanced, under print, ensure that 'Print field codes instead of their values' is unchecked.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: yes, that works too, but instead of setting, there is shortcut for "undo, or do" that command.